# jQuery Bind on children element of dynamically created parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, parent, children

So I am struggling to handle the click of a children which got dynamically created.

Here's the DOM:

```
<article id="randomly-generated-Id">
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-view video-post">
            <video preload="auto">
                <source src="foo" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="foo" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <div class="sound-toggle off"></div>
            <p class="length">0:43</p>
            <div class="presenting"><span class="play">Play</span></div>
        </div>
    </div
</article>
```

The whole `article` gets created by scrolling.

Iam trying to handle the click on the class `sound-toggle`

None of these worked so far:

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".sound-toggle",function () {
    console.log("clicked");
});

jQuery(document).on("click",".video-post .sound-toggle",function () {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Both should work fine. Check the console for errors

Comment: did u warp this under jQuery(document).ready()

Comment: @PunithJain that doesn't matter for this as they are event handlers delegated to the `document`

Comment: Where is the code that dynamically generates anything? I don't see it. I would suggest that when you generate an element dynamically that you instantiate it with the necessary event handlers .

Comment: @RasmusPuls but that's what the OP *is* doing. They're asking why it's not working. Admittedly we need to see more of the code, though

Comment: This provided code is a tampermonkey script, so i can't provide code from my side. I want to react on the click of the "volume" Button on 9gag to lower the voice, because it's really loud and not adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

It works. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/badar5s9/)

You had a closing `div` tag missing in your HTML, btw. Just before the closing `</article>`

Here's the updated HTML

```
<article id="randomly-generated-Id">
    <div class="post-container">
    <div class="post-view video-post">
        <video preload="auto">
            <source src="foo" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="foo" type="video/webm">
        </video>
        <div class="sound-toggle off">
        </div>
        <p class="length">0:43</p>
        <div class="presenting"><span class="play">Play</span></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

The problem why you weren't able to check this in the console could also be that your `.sound-toggle` div didn't take any height or width.

Comment: Just FYI, 'it works' is a comment not an answer, as if this doesn't work for the OP there must be some underlying problem which this does no t address

Comment: Yes, but I think specifying the problems why it didn't work for the OP qualifies as an answer

Comment: Probably working for you because you didn't create the element dynamically.

Comment: @CANi Did you try to add the missing `</div>` and give height and width to `.sound-toggle`?

Comment: This provided code is a tampermonkey script, so i can't provide code from my side, i fixed the given HTML since it was a msitake by me. I want to react on the click of the "volume" Button on 9gag to lower the voice, because it's really loud and not adjustable.

Comment: Can't say more unless there's more of the code. But this should work even if it's being loaded dynamically. Unless, it's being loaded inside an iFrame

Comment: Hello, go on 9gag.com and inject it into your developer console. Scroll down until new "GIFS" get loaded. Then try to click on the volume icon.

    jQuery(document).on("click",".sound-toggle",function () {
        console.log("WAS MUTED"); vol);
    });

Answer (score 0):

you had a `div` tag not closed,just before `</article>` tag.
btw, suggestion don't give to document bind event, because there may be happend potential mistake.
if you to understand i speek, please feedback. thanks.

Comment: This provided code is a tampermonkey script. I fixed the given HTML since it was a msitake by me. I want to react on the click of the "volume" Button on 9gag to lower the voice, because it's really loud and not adjustable.

Comment: Ok, i don't know how to do. you think again. sorry.